# .dylib file not loaded while loading .so files

Tags: c, redis, shared-libraries, dylib

I wanted to use INCR in redis beyond its maximum value 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. So I write a redis module C code using gmp.h. In C code I read the value in the key (the key to be incremented) and incremented by using functions in gmp.h and then written back to the same key.

I create .o files and then .so files and it works fine in my mac. When I gave the .so file to my friend, the .so file did not load and an error came for her.

> Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib

I guess this happend because my friend not installed gmp in her mac

But I thought it will work. Is there any way to make it work in my friend's macbook without installing the library ?

**Commands used to created .o and .so files**

```
gcc -dynamic -fno-common -std=gnu99 -c -o mycommand.o mycommand.c
ld -o mycommand.so mycommand.o -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -lc -lgmp
```

Comment: Sharing .so isn't recommended AFAIK, but it is very awesome to see someone developing a Redis module

Comment: @ItamarHaber but https://redislabs.com/blog/writing-redis-modules/ says only shared object files be used

Comment: Sure, what I meant is sharing the .so with your friend isn't the way to go :) he/she should compile it on her/his setup.

Comment: @ItamarHaber  can you please add this as answer, so I upvote and the question is closed